# Discord.py mention application command

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a help menu for my discord bot, and would like to make it similar to MEE6's, where it mentions application commands.
But rather than typing myself each command by hand, I would like to automate the process, so that if I add a new command it automatically adds it to the list.

I can easily obtain the commands with `tree.get_commands()`, but I don't know how to mention them: I found that typing "</command_name:command_id>" works, but I find nowhere on the docs how to get the id of an application command. Currently the only way I know of is with Discord Developer Mode.

Is there something I'm missing?

[image: Here is what I'm trying to obtain]

Comment: Why can't you just copy the IDs of all your commands manually?

Comment: Because I would like it to be automatic, so I don't have to do it manually each time I add a new one

Comment: You can use `bot.tree.walk_commands(type=discord.AppCommandType.chat_input)` which return a list of  app_command, you can have a look at [this WIP](https://github.com/PaulMarisOUMary/Discord-Bot/blob/ae5d70b1655001d148956b70581b2e8973509723/cogs/help.py#L14-L27)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who ecounters this problem: I was not using the correct command.
I wanted to get type `discord.AppCommand`, but `tree.get_commands()` returns `discord.Command`.
So you get all the Application Commands using `await tree.fetch_commands()`, and those actually have the id that can be used to mention the command.